# LM393 dual comparator outputs are not the same

Tags: digital-logic, analog, comparator, distortion

I applied the same signals to both inputs of the LM393P double comparator. The number 2 comparator output gave the expected result (first photo).

[image]

However, when I apply the same signal to comparator 1, there is a distortion in the output 1 (second photo).

[image]

Why do output jumps (like a sawtooth) occur when the input signal falls below the reference signal? At first I thought the device was broken, and I installed a new LM393P, but the result has not changed.

What am I doing wrong here? And why am I getting this error only from output 1?

[image]

Note: Since the two comparators are in one integrated unit, the supply and ground line are common. I had to draw it as two separate comparators in Proteus.

Comment: The applied signal cannot be from a potentiometer, so the schematics do not show the problem. From where does the square wave come from and what are the parameters for it? It looks slightly drooping so is there some capacitor AC coupling?

Answer (score 3):

You are applying a voltage beyond the input range so bad behavior may be expected.

The [LM393 is only](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm393b.pdf) guaranteed to operate down to 0V at the input, and you are applying a negative voltage.

That's assuming the numbers are showing about a real -60mV input. If the probes are x10, and the scope is set to x1, so the actual input is -600mV you would be outside the absolute maximum input ratings and things like phase reversal can occur (as well as damage to the chip if the current is not limited).

[image]

As to why the results are different, it could be some asymmetry due to the layout of the chip, in particular in the second case mentioned above, with unexpected currents flowing through the isolation junctions in the chip.